# ChartJS set default axis

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, chart.js

I were develop the ChartJs on my website but the problem I can't set the axis of my line Chart so can anyone help to solve this problem?

This is view of my current chart :

[image]

This is my chart code :

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["00:00","06:00","12:00", "18:00"],
    datasets : [{
        labels: "PR",
        fillColor : "rgba(247, 70, 74, 0.1)",
        //fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#FF0040",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
    }, {
        label: "QTY",
        fillColor : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)",
        //fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#0000FF",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
    }]
}
```

What i want to display at my chart, is value of the axis
at the current chart it shown 0,20,30,40,50,...,100

I want it set the default to 0,25%,50%,75%,100%

Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qsosLya0/

The trick is the following configuration options:

```
var lineChartOptions = {
  scaleOverride: true,
  scaleSteps: 4,
  scaleStepWidth: 25,
  scaleStartValue: 0,
  scaleLabel: "<%=value%>%"
};
```

Source: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration

Comment: can i ask you again Fly...how about if i want to add some value to the right axis in my chart
so my chart have 2 axis...one with percentage and another with data

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Chart.js is equipped with such a feature.

Comment: yes i agree...lately i found this [https://github.com/Wikunia/Chart.js/tree/Double-Y-Axis](https://github.com/Wikunia/Chart.js/tree/Double-Y-Axis)  so i will try this double scale